# Not able to connect to remote Git enterprise server via Git hub client for Windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have installed git hub client for windows from [Github](https://desktop.github.com/). I am not able to  login on our github enterprise server. Every time it says not able to connect to remote host or it's not an enterprise server.

**I am able to clone repository using git shell over SSH. From command line every thing works fine  but GUI Client is not working.**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for using Gitlab.com through SSH on Github for windows, it won't be exactly the same for your setup but it might help you out.

1. Add your public ssh key from github_rsa.pub (which is found in your .ssh folder) to your SSH keys on Gitlab.com
2. Add a `config` file to your .ssh folder that looks like this

   ```
   Host gitlab.com
   RSAAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
   User mygitlabusername
   ```
3. Clone / pull your repository through Git Bash
4. Drag the folder to Github For Windows

I hope you can get it to work with something similar.